# How to setup a livestream Node js server that accepts RTMP and/or RTSP streams and use WebRTC to stream to clients (browsers)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc, rtmp, live-streaming

I am trying to set up a live streaming server using Node js and stream it to clients. The server needs to cater both RTMP and RTSP incoming streams.

So far, what I have done is to use [node-media-server](https://github.com/illuspas/Node-Media-Server) to accept RTMP streams and remux to HLS/DASH. This is working fine but produces a huge latency of around 10-20 secs which is not acceptable in my application. I need to have low latency (as much as possible, maximum of 1-2 secs delay). I am also trying to avoid using Flash plugins in the client-side since it will be deprecated by end of 2020.

Further research, maybe I can use WebRTC but is there a way to set up a server that still accepts RTMP and even RTSP (maybe convert to RTMP afterward) and then stream via WebRTC? If so, how? Or are there any other suggestions?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think WebRTC is better suited for peer-to-peer streaming. What you're describing seems to be more of a centralized system

Comment: But are there any other options I can use since I really need a low latency live streaming. HLS/DASH doesn't seem to be the best option right now neither using Flash. Need to accept rtmp/rtsp streams from different source and then serve to clients

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @LiewXun Plenty of folks use WebRTC for streams hosted by servers as well.  One of the "peers" can be a server.  It's a common and effective method.

Answer (score 2):

That is possible (and people are doing it today!)

For fun I did [rtmp-to-webrtc](https://github.com/sean-der/rtmp-to-webrtc) which is a Go server that accepts RTMP and serves via WebRTC.

You could easily add a RTSP server and do the same. I haven't done it myself, but there are a few Go RTSP servers out there.

Comment: I see. I'll check your work. Though I'm not familiar with Go. Thank you! So do you think, this would really be the best option for my application? Or do you have any other suggestions that I can try to explore?

Comment: I think it is worth trying out! I am primarily work with Pion, GStreamer, ffmpeg and Janus. I am sure there are lots of other great tools out there though that I just don't know about :)